# Automatically Trim Trailing White Space for properties in Props file loaded into java.util.Properties

Tags: java

I am using java.util.Properties for loading the properties from property file. Is there any way to automatically remove the white spaces for the values when the data is loaded?
Currently i am using :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(/path/to/file);
properties.load(file);
```

Comment: You mean other than using `trim()` on any property values you retrieve?

Comment: i need a one time solution for my application

Comment: You could make a stand-alone program that will read your stored properties file, trim all the values and store back the revised properties.  But unless you fix your app so that it doesn't store property values with trailing spaces,  it won''t be a one-time solution...

Comment: You could also write a new `java.util.Properties` class, so same package, same Name, and try to get the ClassLoader to substitute the original class with that. That is quite hackish, and you might run into `SecurityManager` problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible work around i got is,if it helps some one,this doesn't affect already existing Properties class references.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(/path/to/file);
properties.load(file);
for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(entry.getValue().toString().trim());
}
```

Comment: This is bad for performance, imagine having alot of entries. Also, if you extend the class as I mentioned in my answer, it won't affect already existing class references; you'd only start initializing the new properties class instead.

Comment: Yes, like I said earlier, if you wanted to use @riadrifai's idea of extending `Property`, the only change you'd have to make, aside from writing the `MyProperties` class itself, is to change `new Property()` to `new MyProperty()`.  Polymorphism takes care of the rest...

Comment: Since i have so many classes doing the instantiation for Properties class ,testing for the same is a time taking process

Comment: So now you're going to add the loop after every instantiation..?

Comment: not after instantiation,but after loading ,i.e after properties.load(file);

Comment: This is better since you can run this only once at startup and then the properties are all correctly formatted for any class that needs to fetch them.

Answer (score 3):

You could extend the `Properties` class and override its `getProperty(String key)` method to return a trimmed string.

```
public class MyProperties extends Properties {
    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
         return super.getProperty(key).trim();
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
MyProperties properties = new MyProperties ();
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(/path/to/file);
properties.load(file);
//Now any propery you get will be returned trimmed
properties.getProperty("test"); //will be returned trimmed
```

Comment: that requires re writing of my application wherever I have used Properties class

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be easier to create a method that trims the actual file before loading it?

Comment: You wouldn't have to change every occurrence of `Property` to `MyProperty`, just `new Property()` to `new MyProperty()`.  But cleaning up the properties proactively, either after you load the or just before you save them is a perfectly good way to go as well.

Comment: This has several problems: 1. NPE if property doesn't exist (fixable) 2. relies on `getProperty(String key,String default)` calling `getProperty(String key)` (probably true, but not sure) 3. Doesn't work for `values()` and methods that store the values. The ideal solution is to have the "real" underlying values trimmed.

Comment: It makes more sense to override `put` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Properties config = new Properties();
    String configFile = "config/apps.properties";
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(configFile)) {
        config.load(fr);
        System.out.println(config);
        for (String k : config.stringPropertyNames()) {
            config.setProperty(k, config.getProperty(k).trim());
        }
        System.out.println(config);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.printf("Error: Failed to load config file %s due to exception: %s\n", configFile, ex.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: adding explanation to your answer will be helpful for users